# WDIO / Appium - " TypeError: $(...).waitForDisplayed is not a function" in my test

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to learn to automate End2end testing a React-native mobile App using WDIO and Appium.

The target component I am trying to click in this problem is this:

[image: Component screen shot]

I got an error of TypeError: $(...).waitForDisplayed is not a function" in my current test project. While I got "elements not found" when I'll do assync mode.

I can verify that the IDs are visible in Appium Element Inspector

[image: ScreenShot here]

Below are my codes (#1 & #2) Either way, I got an error. I really need to understand why I got this errors.
#1

```js
    describe('Test Unit - Assync Mode', () => {
      it('Client must be able to login in the app. ', async () => { 
        // pay attention to `async` keyword
        const el = await $('~pressSkip') // note `await` keyword
        await el.click()
        await browser.pause(500)
      })
    })
```

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

#2

```js
    beforeEach(() => {
       $('~pressSkip').waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 20000 })
    })
    
    describe('My Simple test', () => {
      it('Client must be able to login the app', () => {
        // Click Skip button id: "pressSkip"
        $('~pressSkip').click();
        // Enter Login
          // Email id: "loginEmail"
          // Password id: "loginPwd"
        // Click Login Button id:
      });
    });
```

**Wdio.conf.js**

```
    const { join } = require('path');
    
    exports.config = {
    //
    // ====================
    // Runner Configuration
    // ====================
    //
    // WebdriverIO allows it to run your tests in arbitrary locations (e.g. locally or
    // on a remote machine).
    runner: 'local',
    //
    // ==================
    // Specify Test Files
    // ==================
       
    specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'],
    // ============
    // Capabilities
    // ============
    //
    capabilities: [{
    // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/
    // This is `appium:` for all Appium Capabilities which can be found here
    'appium:platformName': 'Android',
    'appium:deviceName': 'emulator-5554',
    'appium:platformVersion': '8.1.0',
    'appium:newCommandTimeout': '60',         
    'appium:app': join(process.cwd(), '/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'),
    }],
    //
    // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
    // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
        bail: 0,
    //
    // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
    // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
    // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
    // gets prepended directly.
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:/wd/hub',
    //
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
        waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
        connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    //
    // Default request retries count
        connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    // Test runner services
    // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
    // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
    // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
        services: [['appium',{
        // This will use the globally installed version of Appium
        command: 'appium',
        args: {
        basePath: "/wd/hub",
    // This is needed to tell Appium that we can execute local ADB commands
    // and to automatically download the latest version of ChromeDriver
        relaxedSecurity: true,}
    }]],
    port: 4723,
    hostname: "localhost",
    // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
    // before running any tests.
    framework: 'jasmine',
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
        reporters: ['spec'],
    //
    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
        jasmineOpts: {
    // Jasmine default timeout
       defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    //
    // The Jasmine framework allows interception of each assertion in order to log the state of the application
    // or website depending on the result. For example, it is pretty handy to take a screenshot every time
        },
    }
```

Comment: Hello Bong! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are you sure the element exists in the dom and there is no issue with selector?

Comment: Hi Raju - thanks for your reply. I can verify my accessibility IDs when I'm going to use/check it with Appium's Element inspector (Desktop). I believe those components are being rendered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
describe('Test Unit - Assync Mode', () => {
  it('Client must be able to login in the app. ', async () => { 
    // pay attention to `async` keyword
    await (await $('~pressSkip')).waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 20000 })
    const el = await $('~pressSkip') // note `await` keyword
    await el.click()
    await browser.pause(500)
  })
})
```

add await to the waitfordisplay also

Comment: Hi @PDHide, thanks for your answer. It's so weird that even I did exactly your way and even increased the timeout to 200,000.   Still didn't go well. 

I wonder if these errors are the culprit?
#1
INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2021-06-12T12:28:34.679Z ERROR @wdio/appium-service: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 2)
#2
ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 2)

Comment: Try using waitfor exist than visibility

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped a lot.

Comment: By now as of 2/6/2022, webdriverio mentioned 7.9 on will not need to do double or triple await and it can still chain.  I have webdriverio 7.16.14   nodejs 16.13.2.  For some reason, first time installed/upgrade works, then all of a sudden, I can't even start my test, it already showed:  TypeError: $(...).waitForDisplayed is not a function.  Worst yet, await $('selector').setValue('abc') used to work, now I have to do await browser.$('selector').setValue(... I can't find anywhere else that talks about this error.  Any idea?

Comment: @Nate could you create a reproducible example and raise a issue webdriverio git page , will have a look

Comment: @PDHide Thanks for your reply here, which prompted me to do even more debug and POC.  I realized this line:  const { default: $ } = require('webdriverio/build/commands/browser/$'); was added to my file by other npm install or something, which forced me to use browser.$("selector").waitForDisplayed();.  which originally, I didn't have 'browser' before the '$'.  So after taking that line out, it works now.  Now I need to find out why that line was added.  Or how...

Comment: @NateR something messed up the global browser object it seems , see if someone accidently added it else raise a issue to the package that did it ( I dont think some package would do it )

Comment: VSCode is the culprit here, I realized if I typed $ after a closed bracket by mistake, or any other thing after a ), it added that const definition automatically.  What a nuisance.